# How do I solve this simple integral?

Tags: integration

$$\int^3_1 (x^2+x+10) \, dx$$

I have been trying for an hour to solve this one, it shouldn't be that hard I suppose, but I'm just not getting it right.

Please help me :)

Comment: Is it $$\int_1^3(10+x+x^2) dx$$  ?? Then use $\int x^mdx=\frac{x^{m+1}}{m+1}$ for $m+1\ne0$

Answer (score 4):

$$\int^3_1{(x^2+x+10)}\,dx\quad = \quad\int_1^3 x^2 \,dx\; +\; \int_1^3 x\,dx + \;
\;10 \int_1^3 x^0\,dx$$

You need to use the *power rule* for integration:

$$\int x^n\,dx=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} + C,\quad n\neq -1$$

Then, recall $$F(x) = \int f(x)\,dx\implies\int_a^b f(x)\,dx = F(b) - F(a)$$